# boost.python interpreter instantiation

Tags: c++, boost-python

I need to use `boost::python`, but I want the interpreter context to be destroyed after the python interaction has finished.

How and when exactly is the python interpreter being instantiated, and how do I destroy all the resources allocated by it?

**Update** Apparently `Py_Finalize` is not designed to be called many times in the same process. It seems this approach won't work: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#l2h-652

Answer (score 0):

Py_Finalize is designed to only be called once per process.  The way I handled it is to put it into the shutdown hook for our application, or run it at the end of the main function.  You can have multiple instances of the interpreter context and those get cleaned up when their "__main__" object (the one created by import("__main__") ) is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Python does not support safely calling [`Py_Finalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize).

Per the [Embedding - Getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html) section:

> Note that at this time you must not call `Py_Finalize()` to stop the interpreter. This may be fixed in a future version of boost.python.

Additional details are noted in the [TODO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/todo.html#pyfinalize-safety).  In short, some internal Boost.Python objects will remain alive during `Py_Finalize()`, and only attempt to be deleted when Boost.Python unloads, causing the objects to attempt deletion with a non-existent interpreter.